# Tracking outbound links using universal analytics's hitCallback function

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, google-analytics

I am using google analytics new Universal Analytics and I want to track outbound links. Currently I am doing this using

```
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action) { 
ga('send', 'event', category, action);
setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
}
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com'); return false;">
```

I, however, want to use the new hitCallback function to avoid the timeout and potentially missing clicks made by users with slow connections. I've tried

```
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action) { 
ga('send', 'event', category, action, {'hitCallback': function() {
alert('analytics.js done sending data');
}
 }
  );
    }
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax doesn't look like it matches the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback

> the send command allows you to specify a hitCallback function in the
>   **field name** object

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `ga` is missing an argument. You need to pass `link` as fifth argument before the dictionary with the hit callback. You also need to be aware that the hit callback will not be executed if the visitor has blocked Google Analytics. The following article explains how to implement this correctly:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/24/outbound-link-tracking.html